# Is it possible to run python scripts from webinterface?

Tags: php, python, django, google-app-engine, python-webbrowser

One of my project needs me to run a Python scripts that are present on VPS. Is it possible to run those scripts from web interface? There are web development platforms out there like Django. Can those can help me in this project?

Example:
I need to set a cronjob from web interface on Ubuntu VPS.
I want some specific task to happen at some specific time, so for that I need to set a cronjob.

Is it possible?

Or, can I directly launch that Python script from interface without setting a cronjob?

If both case are possible please suggest. It will be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: i realy can't see a possible relationship between cronjobs and web interfaces, but both are possible.

Comment: @JacerOmri thanks all i need to set a time for execution of scripts that is why cronjob. And launching script directly is for real time execution.If you have any ideas please share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to understand what you need here. I'll explain a couple of solutions, pick the one you need.

1. You can edit the cron table [with python and django](http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/wiki/Install) to start whatever you need to start at a specific time
2. You can create a python web interface that calls your python script
3. You can use any languages you want and find the equivalent of [python subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) that allows you to run scripts
4. Edit the cron table with any languages you want

Comment: Thanks but the VPS is on remote location.So that will not be a problem for these??? and 1 ques more we can use Django to run script directly ??

Comment: You can try to connect to this VPS using ssh and then the script, or make it accessible through a web interface that will execute what I show in my answer